# how to transfer genesis block reward for blackcoin?

Tags: genesis-block

So my genesis block has a reward setup but I want to send it to my wallet. can you please tell me how? I am using black coin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reward of genesis block is unspendable.

see https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Genesis_block